# how to remove specific portion from a file using a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a file abc.txt and I want to remove specific portion in a file from a bash script.

```
#######################Media######################
[Media]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share22
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Add#######################
[Add]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share33
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Added#####################
[Added]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share44
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
```

and remove below portion from file

```
#######################Add#######################
[Add]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share33
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
```

how can I remove a first portion, second portion or last portion?

Kindly help me!

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Awk` suits best for this kind of text file handling, you may use below one

```
awk '/^[#]+(Add)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(end)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f' file

# OR combined one

awk '/^[#]+(Add|end)[#]+/{if(f){f=0; next}if(/^[#]+(Add)[#]+/)f=1}!f' file
```

Test Results:

Input

```
$ cat file
#######################Media######################
[Media]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share22
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Add#######################
[Add]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share33
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Added#####################
[Added]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share44
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
```

Output - 1 :

```
$ awk '/^[#]+(Add)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(end)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f' file
#######################Media######################
[Media]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share22
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Added#####################
[Added]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share44
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
```

Output - 2 :

```
$ awk '/^[#]+(Add|end)[#]+/{if(f){f=0; next}if(/^[#]+(Add)[#]+/)f=1}!f' file
#######################Media######################
[Media]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share22
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
#######################Added#####################
[Added]
       comment = Media Files
       path = /share44
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest only = no
#######################end#######################
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my issue is resolved. Can you explain the command because I'm new and it'll very helpful for me.

Comment: @ZubairMughal you are welcome, you may read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @ZubairMughal: `awk '/^[#]+(Add)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(end)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f'` variable `f` will be `1` when line starts with one or more `#` `(Add)` and one or more `#` ,  when variable `f` is set and line starts with one or more `#` `(end)` and one more `#` variable `f` becomes `0`; and `next` means go to next line, any expression after `next` keyword will be skipped, `}!f`  remember NOT gate,  as long as variable `f` is zero `awk` prints line/row/record

Comment: @ZubairMughal `sed '/##Add##/,/##end##/d' file` walter has already given you

Answer (score 2):

The given input is fit for an easy solution:

```
awk '/##Add##/,/##end##/ {next};1'  abc.txt
```

or

```
sed '/##Add##/,/##end##/d' abc.txt
```